# MySQL Query COUNT Output

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get information from another SELECT inside of the same query, however I am not too sure how to get the required field I am after.

```
SELECT t.`id`, t.`title`, t.`author`, t.`content`, ctitle, cid, comments

FROM `tutorials` AS `t`, 

  (
    SELECT tc.`id` as `cid`, tc.`title` as `ctitle` 
    FROM `tutorial_categories` AS `tc` 
    WHERE `title` LIKE '%category title'
  ) AS `c`,

  (
    SELECT COUNT(com.`id`) as `comments`
    FROM `tutorial_comments` AS `com`
    WHERE `tutorial_id` = c.cid
  ) as `comments`

WHERE t.`category` = c.`cid` AND t.`status` = '1'
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

I am trying to fetch the id from `tutorial_categories` and use it in `tutorial_comments`. All I am trying to do as the final output is get the count of how many comments are listed for each tutorial.

Cheers,

Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jacob

You need add a group by clause like this

```
select t.id, t.tilte, t.author, t.content, count(com.id) as comments
from tutorials as t
   join tutotials_categories as cat
      on t.category = cat.id
   join tutorials_comments as com
      on com.tutorial_id = t.id
where cat.title like'%category title'
   and t.status = 1
group by com.id
order by t.id asc
```

I used the ansi join form

Comment: now it's only displaying results that have comments, rather than all the results per the category.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't catch what you mean. You can try left join to display those tutorials that don't have comments, and you can order by category to sort the result set. btw, I think you can try @erwin 's script.

Answer (score 1):

This should clean up your query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, t.author, t.content, c.ctitle, c.cid, com.comments
FROM   tutorials AS t
LEFT   JOIN (
    SELECT tutorial_id, COUNT(com.id) as comments
    FROM   tutorial_comments AS com
    GROUP  BY 1
    )  AS com ON com.tutorial_id = t.category
LEFT   JOIN (
    SELECT tc.id as cid, tc.title as ctitle 
    FROM   tutorial_categories AS tc 
    WHERE  title LIKE '%category title'
    )  AS c ON t.category = c.cid
WHERE  t.status = '1'
ORDER  BY t.id
```

The LEFT JOIN prevents that tutorials disappear that don't find a match.
I made that explicit JOINs with JOIN conditions, that is easier to understand and also the proper way.
Your cardinal problem was that you had the join condition for the counted comments inside the brackets instead of outside, which cannot work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one:

```
SELECT t.`id`, t.`title`, t.`author`, t.`content`, c.title, c.cid, ct.comments
FROM `tutorials` AS `t`

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT tc.`id` as `cid`, tc.`title` as `ctitle` 
    FROM `tutorial_categories` AS `tc` 
    WHERE `title` LIKE '%category title'
  ) AS `c` ON t.`category` = c.`cid` 

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(com.`id`) as `comments`
    FROM `tutorial_comments` AS `com`
    group by com.`id`
  ) as `ct` on  ct.`tutorial_id` = c.cid

WHERE t.`status` = '1'
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```